# Multiple parallel edges with with a knee point in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, edge

Is there an easy way to draw multiple parallel edges from one node to another with an knee point (two 90 degree turns) and equally distributed distance between the edges (not really perfect in the demo graphic)?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `double` double line with another `double` line as `postaction`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw,thick,fill=yellow!80!black,minimum size=1cm,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries},
    quadruple/.style={double distance=#1-\pgflinewidth,thick,
        postaction={draw,thick,double distance=#1/3-\pgflinewidth}},
    quadruple/.default=1em]
 \path (0,0) node (A) {A} (3,3) node (B){B};
 \draw[quadruple] (A) -- ++ (1,0) |- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]